# Ember app redirects to /#/Path/ in IE8

Tags: ember.js, internet-explorer-8

I have an Ember app that I am trying to get working in IE8. It works fine in Chrome and other current browsers.

When I try to open the app at `example.com/path/` it redirects to `example.com/#/path`.

Has anyone else had this problem with routing and found a solution?
I am using Ember: 1.12.0, Ember Data: 1.0.0-beta.18 and jQuery: 1.11.3.

Comment: What do you have your router's location set to? http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Location.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE8 doesn't support the history API.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=history In order to use the SPA functionality with the router in IE8 you'll need to use the hash routing.